# Overlaying polygon on other polygons and creating new one using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to write a seeding plan. I created 3 zones and I want to insert a control strip (now I have 3 polygons, in the end I would like to have four). But I just can't merge the two together.

If I merge them, the program merges every polygon into one big one. I tried to run through the forums but I think I just can't write the question correctly.

[image: this is my layer with the contour of the strip i would like to insert]

[image: this is how it should look like in the end]

Comment: I am trying to understand where the 4th polygon is in your example. Could you expand on the question with more pictures showing what you want?

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear on what you mean here. Do you want to create a "hole" in the pink polygon? If so check out the "Editing Toolbar".

Comment: From your picture it looks like you need the Update tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you might want to consider testing a couple of the tools below that are both in ArcToolbox.

1. Identity tool. This would preserve your existing base layer but cut it to your polygon boundary overlay. See more here:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/identity.htm

2. Update tool. This would not preserve your underlying rasterized polygons but would apply your zone boundary to the update feature (your overlaying polygon). See more here:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/update.htm

Comment: @Tanabaj if this answer is what you were looking for please mark the answer as answered and closed. It's the green tick of the left hand side of the answer.